# Application freezes for no reason, no deadlock and impossible to attach to Visual Studio for debugging

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, freeze, ormlite-servicestack

I have a C# .NET 4.6 console application that is supposed to run continuously (over days/months). However, after a non deterministic duration, all running threads will freeze for no apparent reason (CPU usage is at 0%, memory is not particularly high), and trying to attach the application to an instance of Visual Studio 2015 for debugging will fail (pressing "pause" will cause Visual Studio to stop responding!).

I inspected the parallel stack traces (captured via a dump in the process explorer) and could not find any sign of a deadlock (which would otherwise be the obvious culprit).

Here are for example 2 parallel stacks that are frozen (not even in my code but in the `DirectoryInfo.cs` core library, and ServiceStack OrmLite library), even though there are absolutely no reasons for them to be stuck like this.

[image: Parallel stacks]

I have previously noticed this behavior of freezing on other parts of code so it really seems these libraries are "victims" of the freeze and not responsible for it. Even if there were a deadlock which I could not see, it should not prevent these threads from completing as they are not waiting for anything.

Finally, killing the process and restarting it will always allow the previously frozen operations to run successfully.

Do you have any clue on what could be causing this kind of weird behavior/have any advice on tools to be used to get more insight?

Comment: Does it continue after some time?

Comment: No, it gets stuck forever like if there were a deadlock.

Comment: It looks like the two threads are on the same place. It also looks if both are file operations. SQLite usually locks the file when accessing it. Does you "iterating over files" loop (as it seems to be) also trying to lock files? If yes, there is already 50% for a deadlock.

Comment: These are indeed file operations (three threads on the left are trying to read from a SQLite database, the thread on the right is recursively checking if any file within a folder has a specific name in it), however SQLite will normally have already locked the file, and most importantly the SQLite database is not present in the folder that is being iterated over. So I don't think this could explain the issue, especially as if there was any file locking it would eventually throw an exception.

Comment: You need to get your machine stable again before you can debug this.  Preventing a debugger from breaking requires something nasty that patches the kernel.  Get rid of the usual suspects, anti-malware is always on top of that list.  If it is cr*pware like ESET or Avast then get rid of it completely.

Comment: You probably should check if there are any relevant locks in the file system. Use an appropriate tool to check this.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks for the suggestion, however the machine is very clean with no anti-malware or antivirus that could be blocking the process.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger if there were any lock in the file system the program would simply fail with an exception, so it cannot be that :/.

Comment: It is not the first time I notice a problem with Visual Studio 2015 that I never saw with previous versions of the IDE, so the debugger not being able to break in may be related to a bug in Visual Studio (it should always be able to fail properly if for any reason it cannot attached to a program), however it does not explain why the program, in Release mode outside of Visual Studio, will freeze like this.

Comment: I'm experiencing a similiar issue.  I removed threads all together and after a variable amount of time the .Net Core Console program will stop working.  If I go to the console window and press any key, it continues which is baffling (there is no Console.ReadKey() or any other input in the program).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be both threads are hanging while reading information(execute reader reads data from file, Enumerator trying to read data from file system for directory information). Is the file system is accessible at that point of time? Are you able to access the directory in which the reading is happening ?

Comment: The two directories are different (no overlap) so they cannot deadlock each other in any way, and it is possible to access the directory/files externally without problem.

Comment: I am just thinking whether the storage(SAN/NAS) delay contributed something to this hang in the core library.

Comment: This is local storage, there is no such delay that could matter here.